# Parse HTML in VBA to extract information from description list?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to extract information from a website with `Excel XP`.

I found some example code (http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm) and tried the following:

```
Function strHtmlElementValue(htmldoc As HTMLDocument, id As String) As String
Dim HtmlElement As IHTMLElement
Set HtmlElement = htmldoc.getElementById(id)
strHtmlElementValue = id & ": " & HtmlElement.innerText
End Function
```

I tried it with the following URL (loaded as the `htmldoc`): http://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/73940554

If I use the string "expose-title" for the id, the function returns the title of the page, which is fine.

But how can I access e. g. information like the price?

In the Html code, it looks like that. There is no ID and if I try to use the class-name "is24qa-kaufpreis" for `getelementbyid`, I get an error message.

```
   <dl>
        <dt>
          <strong class="is24qa-kaufpreis-label">
            Kaufpreis:
          </strong>
        </dt>
        <dd class="is24qa-kaufpreis">
          2.190.000,00 EUR
        </dd>
  </dl>
```

So, is there a way to access fields like this "is24qa-kaufpreis" directly and read out the inner text (in this case the *2.190.000,00 EUR*?

Comment: What you want is `getElementsByClassName` - note that this returns a *collection* of matching elements, so you can do something like: `Dim els: Set els = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("is24qa-kaufpreis")` Then `els(0)` will contain the first match from your document.  Note: `getElementsByClassName` first appeared in IE9, so not sure if that will be available on your system.

Comment: @TimWilliams First thing I tried was a couple of variations of getElementsByClassName("is24qa-kaufpreis") and couldn't get them to work (I'm running IE11).  If you try it, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways you could go about it.  The following code shows two approaches based on "getElementsByTagName."  In the source code for the web page, if you can count which instance of div "dd" kaufpreis is in, then you could use the first method.  A more general approach is shown following it.

```
Sub test()
    my_url = "http://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/73940554"
    Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
    xml_obj.send
    html_doc.body.innerhtml = xml_obj.responseText
    Set xml_obj = Nothing

    k_pice = html_doc.body.getElementsByTagName("dd")(0).innertext

' Or

    Set Results = html_doc.body.getElementsByTagName("dd")
    For Each itm In Results
        If InStr(1, itm.outerhtml, "EUR", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            k_price = itm.innertext
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.  IE11, but should work with IE9+.

```
Sub TestGEBCN()

Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, html, els

    html = "<dl><dt><strong class=""is24qa-kaufpreis-label"">Kaufpreis:" & _
           "</strong></dt><dd class=""is24qa-kaufpreis"">" & _
           "2.190.000,00 EUR</dd></dl>"

    doc.body.innerHTML = html

    Set els = doc.getElementsByClassName("is24qa-kaufpreis")

    Debug.Print els(0).innerText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).InnerText
```

for Kaufpreis;

Use

```
getElementsByTagName("dd")(0).InnerText
```

for 2.190.000,00 EUR.

(0) is the number of the same tag element, there can be many entries with the same tag name in the code, to retrieve them use ("tag")(0), ("tag")(1),...,("tag")(n).

I suggest researching the topics regarding child or sub elements for automation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that Excel can do it's own web queries. On the Data - Import External Data - New Web Query menu (Alt + D, D, W). Then you would refer to it as sheet2!a22 or whatever. It no good for a page that constantly changes it's layout.

Comment: I tried that first, but was not sure how to get the wanted information then. I assume that not on all such pages the price e. g. would have occured in the same cell and there were no tables to select, so I'd have to fetch the whole page. But definitely, that's also an interesting option.

Answer (score 1):

**[CSS selector:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)**

[.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of HTMLDocument to apply a CSS selector of `dd[class='is24qa-kaufpreis']`

This says get first element with tag name `dd` having `class` attribute of i`s24qa-kaufpreis'`. `"[]"` means attribute.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: css query]

---

**VBA:**

```
htmldocument.querySelector("dd[class='is24qa-kaufpreis']").innerText
```

You need to obtain the HTMLDocument object but the other answers already show meothds for this.